# Why does the pulmonary artery have higher glucose concentration than the pulmonary vein?

Tags: breathing

If the pulmonary artery have higher glucose concentration than the pulmonary vein, does it mean glucose will be consumed during gas exchange?

That confused me because gas exchange is something like diffusion and shouldn't consume any glucose

Comment: So what about the red cells flowing in the pulmonary artery? And its endothelial cells?

Comment: @GrahamChiu So during the gas exchange, red cells will proceed cellular respiration as soon as it absorb oxygen?

Comment: I didn't say that

Comment: I said that because glucose will be decomposed in order to proceed cellular respiration. 

**Edit:** I didn't know that red cells don't have mitochondria

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/34753/22415

Comment: I still don't get it. If glycolysis does not require oxygen, then why glucose will be metabolized during breath exchange? Breath exchange seems have nothing to do with glycolysis.

Comment: Lung tissue is living and requires glucose. The answer is correct.

Comment: @nongoodnurse the answer should mention the role of the bronchial arteries. As it stands it is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gas exchange doesn't but the cells of the tissue it occurs in do consume glucose, even the cells in the walls of the artery will consume some.  The cells in the lungs still need to be fed and only one of those two vessels has flow going into the tissue so it is the one that has to carry that glucose into the tissue.